# Setting up $httpBackend inside test files

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-e2e

when running my e2e tests i setup fixtures like this in a bootstrap file:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [dependencies]);
var appTest = angular.module('appTest', ['myApp', 'ngMockE2E']);
appTest.run(function($httpBackend) {
  $httpBackend.whenGET('/api/products').respond(someResponseObject);
});
```

then a have separated files for each the scenarios i want to test. How can I setup the $httpBackend and fixtures inside the scenarios files (thus, potentially have different setups) instead of in a single bootstrap file? It tends to get long and unreadable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject $httpBackend to your specs in scenario files, like below:

```
http = undefined 

beforeEach inject(function($httpBackend){
  http = $httpBackend
});
```

And setup the fixture as required in scenario files like below:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  http.whenGET('/api/products').respond(someResponseObject);
});
```